# In angular 10, different results while compiling the same HTML tags with ngstyle and others directives?

Tags: angular, compilation

I have this code, in .html

`<div style="float:left ;" [ngStyle]="{'width.%': CurrentRankPercent, 'height.px': 5}"></div>`

The above code compiles ok.

then I add the follow: , 'background-color': 0xFF

```
        <div style="float:left ;" [ngStyle]="{'width.%': CurrentRankPercent, 'height.px': 5, 'background-color': 0xFF }"></div>
```

It compiles wrong, so, I press CTRL-Z, to undo all changes (and then I just add and remove an useless space anywhere else so it is like the file surelly is taken as changed), save all menú option (last visual studio code), and then see how it compiles,

Now, the code that before was compiling OK, now COMPILES ERROR (Yes, I checked that the CMD console really is alive and re-runing the compilation process and not stuck in text select mode), don't matter how many times I try to recompile it, it throws errors.

So, I press, CTRL+C, YES,  and write again,   ng serve -o  (windows)

and it now compiles, ok!.

What I am doing wrong? This is turning me crazy. It is like a new-developers trap?

The errors are:  Parser Error: Missing expected } at column..., but there is the closing...

But in the following compilations for the SAME code, returns " Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.", which is a lie, because Common is imported, worked the first time, etc.

so, CTRL+C , YES, and ng serve -o, again , again and again.

Also I don't know, why : 255 works, and : 0xFF doesn't work? I am assuming ngStyle is expecting typescript lang. not normal CSS as the sharp #FF didn't work.

Comment: `'background-color': '#FF'`

Comment: ok that worked for this specific error, but, don't answer WHY i needed to CTRL+C and ng serve -o again, to get it to work. 

AND only I need to do that if it gets an error, if I am compiling OK, and making changes, all the changes (if compile ok) will show in the browser, perfect, no problem . But, one time compiling one error, it will be stuck, compiling errors again and again, don't matter if I fix the source, it will throw errors,  until CTRL+C, ng serve -o, and will compile ok